# Was Edmund in the Narnia series loosely inspired by Edmund in King Lear?

Tags: william-shakespeare, inspiration, c-s-lewis, the-chronicles-of-narnia, king-lear

In *King Lear*, Edmund, resentful of his inferior status to his older brother, betrays his family and frames his brother as a traitor. This strikes me as being quite a bit like what Edmund does in *The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe*. Is there any evidence of an inspiration, or is the resemblance purely coincidental?

Comment: [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2005/dec/04/cslewis.film) claims so, but without sources or evidence.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Interesting... so, I may not be completely crazy here. I wish that they provided more evidence or sources for that, though.

Comment: I just re-read and was thinking this also!  His suffering in the book reminds me of Edgar, and Edgar/Edmund, half-brothers, were clearly meant to be flip sides of the same coin.  *(I doubt it's coincidental, since Lewis was extremely literate, and the best authors tend not to name characters randomly.)*  But I'm not enough of a Lewis scholar to know if he wrote or spoke about the parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I’ve been able to find, Lewis never spoke explicitly about a connection, but as Rand al'Thor noted, others have made the same connection. David L. Johns offers a full chapter in *Quakering Theology* making the case that the two Edmunds are connected which is fairly compelling. But without any explicit statement from Lewis, we can never say for certain, even if it is likely that Lewis did make the deliberate choice to name his Edmund after Shakespeare’s.

Comment: Could you summarize Johns' argument? What makes it compelling?